# Get posts and comment marked as spam

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In my fan pages, in FQL or Graph API,
I would like to get posts and comment which have been marked as spam.

And in a second time I want to "mark as spam" with graph API for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a fb bug report related to this.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/156137637817779

The priority is wishlist. :(